# Proof that $12$ in a row tic-tac-toe is a tie game?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, tessellations, magic-square

How can be it proved that tic-tac-toe on an infinite grid (winning with $12$ in a row, a column or a diagonal) can always end in a tie (with optimal strategies of both players)?

There is a hint: to use a "magic square of $4\times4$" and a "tessellation".

Comment: Tic-tae-toe on an infinite grid can never *end* in a tie. Presumably you mean that neither player has a winning strategy.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I define tie as "not making 12 in a row, a column or a diagonal", so the infinite play is a tie. You are right about the inappropriateness of the verb "end", though.

Comment: There's a proof in one of the later volumes of *Winning Ways* that the 9-in-a-row game is a draw on an infinite board.  A fortiori the 12-in-a-row game is too.

Comment: @PeterTaylor According to the rules, the game **ends** after $\omega$ moves if nobody has made $12$ in a row. One could consider a variant, where play continues into the transfinite as long as there are any unoccupied points, but this is not so popular.

Comment: @MJD *Winning Ways* (in the edition that I have) has only two volumes. A drawing strategy for $9$-in-a-row is shown in vol. 2, figure 12 on p. 677. By the way, your *a fortiori* would be hard to justify. Fortunately, the same strategy works for $n$-in-a-row for all $n\ge9.$ That's because it's purely defensive; it blocks the opponent from making $9$-in-a-row, it does not depend on counterattacking by threatening to make one's own $9$-in-a-row.

Comment: @bof Mine is in two volumes also, but there is a new(er) edition by A.K. Peters in which the four parts (“Spade work”, “A change of heart”, etc.) are in four separate volumes.

Comment: @bof: Can you explain what you mean by "hard to justify"? MJD's argument seems straightforward: the second player has a drawing strategy in 9-in-a-row, so if the second player plays that strategy in the 12-in-a-row game, then the first player never gets a row of length 9, and so never gets a row of length 12 either.

Comment: @GarethRees Consider ordinary tic-tac-toe on $3\times3$ board. Note that the second player **can not block** the first player making a row of $3$: 1. a1 b2 2. c3 b1 3. a3 b3 4. a2 and player one has $3$ counters on the $a$-file. Of course player two got $3$ counters on the $b$-file. Player can force a draw in ordinary tic-tac-toe, but only because he can **counterattack** by threatening to make his own $3$-in-a-row. **If** the drawing strategy for $9$-in-a-row relied on counterthreats, it would **not** be clear that it works for $10$-in-a-row.

Comment: @GarethRees See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994408/converting-a-gomoku-winning-strategy-from-a-small-board-to-a-winning-strategy-on/994604#994604) and note the Open Problems, esp. 5.3.

Comment: @bof: I understand your point now. But the proof from *Winning Ways* that MJD referred to does not rely on counterattacks: it's a Hales-Jewett pairing strategy.

Comment: @GarethRees Yes, I know. I remarked on that fact in my comment to MJD, and again in my reply to your comment, by bolding "**If**". The only reason for my comment to MJD was that he did not mention the pairing strategy but only reported that "the 9-in-a-row game is a draw", which I thought could be misleading.