# Converting a Gomoku winning strategy from a small board to a winning strategy on a larger board

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

*Gomoku* is the game where Black and White take turns placing stones of their own color, and the winner is the player who first gets five of their own stones in a row.  Black moves first.

In [Gomoku on an infinite big board](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987452/), I made the following claim:

> If Black can win on a $15\times 15$ board, he can certainly win on an infinite board, since he can *pretend* to be playing on a $15\times 15$ board, and if White plays outside the imaginary boundary, so much the better for Black.

I am no longer happy with this argument. Here is a counterargument:

> Suppose Black pretends to be playing on a $15\times 15$ board, making all his moves inside the imaginary boundary of a $15\times 15$ region.  If White has the opportunity to make any five moves outside the imaginary boundary before Black wins inside the boundary, White will win first.  Thus if White can find a strategy $S$ for the $15\times 15$ board that delays Black's win long enough for her to pass five times, then she can win on the infinite board by playing $S$ against Black, and using her pass moves to play outside the imaginary boundary.

My idea is that Black's winning strategy might take a long time to execute, say 103 moves, and perhaps pass moves by White only allow Black to speed up his win  by a moderate amount; say by passing at the correct times, White can still force Black to take 37 moves to win.  Then despite Black's winning strategy for the $15\times 15$ board, White can win on the infinite board if Black does not defend outside the $15\times15$ region.

One of the two arguments must fail. Right now, I think it's the first one that fails. My questions are:

1. Is there some reason that I've overlooked that the notional winning strategy $S$ for White can't exist?
2. If there isn't, *does* such a strategy exist?
3. Is there any way in general to convert winning strategies on smaller boards to winning strategies on a larger boards?

Comment: This is an interesting question! Is there also a possible counterstrategy where white combines some moves at the edge of the 15 by 15 region with some moves outside that region so as to win?

Comment: @paw88789: only if black refuses to move outside the $15 \times 15$  Otherwise, the strategy stealing argument works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In József Beck's book [*Combinatorial Games: Tic-Tac-Toe Theory*](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/discrete-mathematics-information-theory-and-coding/combinatorial-games-tic-tac-toe-theory), he states the following open problems ("unrestricted $5$-in a row" is Gomoku on an infinite board):

> **Open Problem 4.1.** *Is it true that unrestricted $5$-in-a-row is a first player win?*
>   
> **Open Problem 4.2.** *Is it true that unrestricted $n$-in-a-row is a draw for every $n\ge6$?*

There are some relevant counterexamples in the more general setting of "positional games". The following information is from pp. 78-84 of József Beck's book.

A *positional game* is defined by a *hypergraph* $(V,E)$ where $V$ is the *vertex set* (or *board*) and $E$ is the set of *(hyper-)edges* (or *winning sets*), a collection of nonempty finite subsets of $E$. Two players take turns picking (previously unpicked) vertices; the game is won by the first player to succeed in picking all the vertices of a winning set.

The following example, attributed to Fred Galvin, illustrates what Beck calls "the Induced Extra Set Paradox". The board is $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$; the winning sets are $\{1,2,3\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,4,5\},\{1,2,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{4,5,7\},\{6,7\}$. This game is a draw, but it becomes a first-player win if the board is restricted to the subset $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with winning sets $\{1,2,3\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,4,5\},\{1,2,5\}$.

In Galvin's example the hypergraph is *non-uniform*, meaning that the winning sets are not all the same size. Here is a slightly larger example of the same phenomenon, attributed to Sujith Vijay, where the winning sets are all triples: the board is $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, the winning sets are $\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,5,6\},\{3,5,7\},\{2,4,8\},\{2,6,9\}$. This game is a draw, but the restriction to the board $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ is a first-player win.

Beck states the following open problems concerning generalized Tic-Tac-Toe, analogous to your question 3:

> **Open Problem 5.2** *Is it true that, if the $n^d$ Tic-Tac-Toe is a first player win, then the $n^D$ game, where $D\gt d$, is also a win?*
>   
> **Open Problem 5.3.** *Is it true that, if the $n^d$ game is a draw, then the $(n+1)^d$ game is also a draw?*

Comment: This was an unusually helpful answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the strategy stealing argument works on all board sizes to prove white cannot win.  I agree that it is possible that black must play outside the original $15 \times 15$ to block white.  You are assuming that black will select at the start a $15 \times 15$ area to play in that will be a win, but that is not required.  If the board is $19 \times 19$, black is allowed to play anywhere on the board.  I can't see an easy proof that black winning on $15 \times 15$ proves he wins on all larger boards.  It could be that the flow in the$15 \times 15$ case lets white make threats on a larger board that take more moves for black to counter than white took to set up.  That would allow some board sizes greater than $15 \times 15$ to be a draw, but no way white wins.