# Is there a generic algorithm to solve m,n,k games?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

In an $m,n,k$ board game, two players take turns in placing a stone of their color on an $m×n$ board, the winner being the player who first gets $k$ stones of their own color in a row, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

The $m=3, \quad n=3, \quad k=3$ game is the classic tic-tac-toe.

Is there a generic solution for all such $m,n,k$ games, or is it not possible?

It is known that, if both players perform perfect play (optimal strategy):

- $k ≥ 9$ is a draw.
- $ k > m$ or $k > n$ is a draw.

Comment: These games are all finite, so a generic algorithm is to exhaustively search the game tree.

Comment: This answer is relevant and the reference it cites may be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/994604/25554